# I need help on this simple percentage web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help! When you press each button it is supposed to append the percentage for that button in the body. For some reason it doesn't seem to be showing it though.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var numOfPressedOne = 0;
    var numOfPressedTwo = 0;
    var totalPressed = 0;
    var buttonOnePct = numberOfPressedOne/totalPressed;
    var buttonTwoPct = 0;

    var pressedOne = function(){
        numberOfPressedOne ++;
        totalPressed ++;
        $("body").append(buttonOnePct + "%");       
    };

    var pressedTwo = function(){
        numberOfPressedTwo ++;
        totalPressed ++;
        $("body").append(buttonTwoPct + "%");       
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="buttonOne" value="press" onclick="pressedOne;"/>
    <input type="button" id="buttonTwo" value="press" onclick="pressedTwo;"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're referencing your functions but you're not calling them. Try something like this:

```
<input type="button" id="buttonOne" value="press" onclick="pressedOne()" />
```

**EDIT:** Your function also isn't creating any new elements. Try the following:

```
var pressedOne = function() {
    numberOfPressedOne ++;
    totalPressed ++;
    $("body").append("<p>" + buttonOnePct + "%</p>");
};
```

Comment: @user3354230 You're right, I missed something critical. Check my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of problems with the code you had.
Here's my take on it:

```
<script>
    var numberOfPressedOne = 0;
    var numberOfPressedTwo = 0;
    var totalPressed = 0;
    var buttonOnePct = numberOfPressedOne/totalPressed;
    var buttonTwoPct = 0;

    var pressedOne = function(){
        numberOfPressedOne ++;
        totalPressed ++;
        buttonOnePct = numberOfPressedOne/totalPressed;
        $("body").append("<br\>button 2: " + buttonOnePct*100 + "%");
    };

    var pressedTwo = function(){
        numberOfPressedTwo ++;
        totalPressed ++;
        buttonTwoPct = numberOfPressedTwo/totalPressed
        $("body").append("<br\>button 1: " + buttonTwoPct*100 + "%");
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="buttonOne" value="press" onclick="pressedOne();"/>
    <input type="button" id="buttonTwo" value="press" onclick="pressedTwo();"/>
</body>
```

Firstly, you were using variables named both `numberOfPressedOne` AND `numOfPressedOne`

Secondly, `buttonOnePct` and `buttonTwoPct` need to be updated EVERYTIME the user clicks

Thirdly, the buttons need to be `onclick="pressedOne();"` instead of `onclick="pressedOne;"`

And lastly, I added some code to prettify the output making it go `"<br\>button 1: " + buttonTwoPct*100 + "%"` but you can revert this if you want to.

Comment: Please explain, what problem you had recognized.

Comment: @omeinusch I have added some explanation on what the problems were. Hopefully it clears things up